# Leveraging for loop to run slices of dataframe through supervised model based on one column value

Tags: python, pandas, random-forest, train-test-split, hardcode

I have the following dataframe and would like to group the data by `cluster` number to generate 5 new dataframes (the clusters go from 0-4), and then further split them up into training and test sets based on the `Date` column and run each train/test dataframe through a Random Forest regressor.
[image: df]

I have been able to achieve this in a heavily hard-coded way via:

```py
cluster_1 = whatever_df[whatever_df['cluster'] == 0]
cluster_2 = whatever_df[whatever_df['cluster'] == 1]
cluster_3 = whatever_df[whatever_df['cluster'] == 2]
cluster_4 = whatever_df[whatever_df['cluster'] == 3]
cluster_5 = whatever_df[whatever_df['cluster'] == 4]

train_1 = cluster_1[cluster_1['Date'] <= max(cluster_1['Date']) - relativedelta(months = 3)]
test_1 = cluster_1[cluster_1['Date'] > max(cluster_1['Date']) - relativedelta(months = 3)]

train_2 = cluster_2[cluster_2['Date'] <= max(cluster_2['Date']) - relativedelta(months = 3)]
test_2 = cluster_2[cluster_2['Date'] > max(cluster_2['Date']) - relativedelta(months = 3)]

train_3 = cluster_3[cluster_3['Date'] <= max(cluster_3['Date']) - relativedelta(months = 3)]
test_3 = cluster_3[cluster_3['Date'] > max(cluster_3['Date']) - relativedelta(months = 3)]

train_4 = cluster_4[cluster_4['Date'] <= max(cluster_4['Date']) - relativedelta(months = 3)]
test_4 = cluster_4[cluster_4['Date'] > max(cluster_4['Date']) - relativedelta(months = 3)]

train_5 = cluster_5[cluster_5['Date'] <= max(cluster_5['Date']) - relativedelta(months = 3)]
test_5 = cluster_5[cluster_5['Date'] > max(cluster_5['Date']) - relativedelta(months = 3)]

columns = whatever_df.columns.tolist()
cols = [c for c in columns if c not in ['Date', 'CPR']]

X_train_1 = train_1[cols]
y_train_1 = train_1['CPR']
X_test_1 = test_1[cols]
y_test_1 = test_1['CPR']


X_train_2 = train_2[cols]
y_train_2 = train_2['CPR']
X_test_2 = test_2[cols]
y_test_2 = test_2['CPR']


X_train_3 = train_3[cols]
y_train_3 = train_3['CPR']
X_test_3 = test_3[cols]
y_test_3 = test_3['CPR']


X_train_4 = train_4[cols]
y_train_4 = train_4['CPR']
X_test_4 = test_4[cols]
y_test_4 = test_4['CPR']


X_train_5 = train_5[cols]
y_train_5 = train_5['CPR']
X_test_5 = test_5[cols]
y_test_5 = test_5['CPR']
```

Followed by:

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
rf_1 = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=5)
rf_1.fit(X_train_1, y_train_1)

y_pred_1 = rf_1.predict(X_test_1)
print('MAE 1: ', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test_1, y_pred_1))
print('MSE 1: ', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test_1, y_pred_1))
print('\n')

rf_2 = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=5)
rf_2.fit(X_train_2, y_train_2)
print('\n')

y_pred_2 = rf.predict(X_test_2)
print('MAE 2: ', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test_2, y_pred_2))
print('MSE 2: ', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test_2, y_pred_2))
print('\n')

rf_3 = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=5)
rf_3.fit(X_train_3, y_train_3)

y_pred_3 = rf.predict(X_test_3)
print('MAE 3: ', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test_3, y_pred_3))
print('MSE 3: ', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test_3, y_pred_3))
print('\n')

rf_4 = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=5)
rf_4.fit(X_train_4, y_train_4)
print('\n')
y_pred_4 = rf.predict(X_test_4)
print('MAE 4: ', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test_4, y_pred_4))
print('MSE 4: ', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test_4, y_pred_4))

rf_5 = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=5)
rf_5.fit(X_train_5, y_train_5)
print('\n')
y_pred_5 = rf.predict(X_test_5)
print('MAE 5: ', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test_5, y_pred_5))
print('MSE 5: ', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test_5, y_pred_5))
```

But I would like to accomplish the same thing without so much copy/paste. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for loop is perfect here!

```
columns = whatever_df.columns.tolist()
cols = [c for c in columns if c not in ['Date', 'CPR']]
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

for i in range(5):
    cluster = whatever_df[whatever_df['cluster'] == i]

    train = cluster[cluster['Date'] <= max(cluster['Date']) - relativedelta(months = 3)]
    test = cluster[cluster['Date'] > max(cluster['Date']) - relativedelta(months = 3)]

    X_train = train[cols]
    y_train = train['CPR']
    X_test = test[cols]
    y_test = test['CPR']

    rf = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=5)
    rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    y_pred = rf.predict(X_test)
    print(f'MAE {i}: ', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))
    print(f'MSE {i}: ', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
    print('\n')
```

Comment: Oh yay, thank you! That's perfect. I've been using Python for a year+ now and I knew a for loop could do it but for some reason, I didn't realize it could be this simple. I was stuck on this idea of creating new variables for each train and test set and was going to try to use multiple variables to generate new, named variables. This saved me a ton of headache!

Comment: Thanks! Some more advice: if you find yourself needing the MAE/MSE after the for loop for some other reason, I recommend initializing a list before the for loop called "stats" or something similar, and then appending your MAE/MSE to that list. That way, you can save the results you need instead of overwriting them every time.